# Automatic creation of method definitions from declarations

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

Is there a tool, macro or plugin that can generate a method or function body automatically from a declaration in a header file?
I have tried Intellisense and Refactor! 3.0.5 which both only seem to work with C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [Visual Assist](http://www.wholetomato.com/). But it is a commercial tool.

Answer (score 0):

If your header file format is regular enough (run it through a formatter), it should be two global search and replaces, then run it through the formatter.